# OpenGL - Multi Sampled FBO methodology

Tags: opengl, game-engine, antialiasing, multisampling

I am implementing Multisampled Antialiasing into my deferred rendering engine and I'm curious, can I simply use a multisampled texture for the albedo output? Or will the depth texture, normals texture and even lighting texture have to be multisampled also?

[image]

Comment: Multisampling and deferred shading don't go well together.  Keeping your g-buffer multisampled would imply that you use per-sample shading in the lighting pass, which would defeat the purpose of multisampling. Resolving the FBO before the lighting pass will just mix the properties of different objects, which will result in wrong lighting at the edges of the objects.

Comment: @Derhass I was kinda hoping that once I have soft shadows working that it would hide the incorrect lighting on the edges..

Comment: Shadows don't help with that at all.

Comment: Yeah MSAA is a major challenge for deferred shading systems. The most common I have seen would be a post-processing filter (edge detection then blur). It doesn't even make sense to have MSAA enabled for the individual GBuffers since you are merely using them as a look up and the final texture is a combination of them which won't be MSAA regardless of your GBuffer since you are responsible for shading it.